Psycopy replay video stimuli associated with button press
We are developing an experiment in Psycopy in which participants watch a video and press a button to indicate when they had a reaction during the video. We want to then show them again the parts of the videos in which they pressed the button to ask them a specific question.
We found only how to replay the entire video in a loop but not how to replay the specific video parts associated with the button press, is it possible in Psycopy to do that?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
